# Entity Framework Core 5 throws System.FormatException in SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core 5.0 application - I try to migrate the app from SqLite DB provider to CosmosDb. I use Entity Framework Core with

- `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.7"`
- `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="5.0.7"`

I use the 'Azure Cosmos DB Emulator' or a "real azure db instance" with no difference. When executing `.SaveChanges()` there are loglines in Visual Studio 2019 output window:

**Exception thrown**:

> 'System.FormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Exception:  The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

- Still my entity(s) are written to the DB!!  But this seems to impact performance.

I created a single file Unit Test Project to demonstrate:

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace UnitTestCosmos
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTestCosmosDb
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public async Task TryWriteDataAsync()
            {
                using (var destinationcontext = new MyDbContext())
                {
                    var item = new MyVerbrauch(){MessId = Guid.NewGuid(), StromHausKwh = 357};
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Try Write ");
                    try
                    {
                        await destinationcontext.MyVerbrauch.AddAsync(item);
                        Debug.WriteLine($"\nSave to  MyDbContext\n");

                        await destinationcontext.SaveChangesAsync(); // throws ??
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Exception:  {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        public class MyVerbrauch
        {
            [Key]
            [Required]
            public Guid MessId { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public int StromHausKwh { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class MyDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<MyVerbrauch> MyVerbrauch { get; set; }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                // Use Cosmos DB
                optionsBuilder.UseCosmos("https://localhost:8081",
                            "< your key>",
                            databaseName: "CosmosDBdemo.cdb");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my first question on stack overfolw and I would appreciate any help!!

Added July 15:

Visual Studio Output Window:

```
    Save to  MyDbContext
    
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Net.Security.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'E:\Andreas\git\CosmosDbTest\CosmosDbTest\bin\Debug\net5.0\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Net.WebClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Buffers.dll'. 
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : DocumentClient with id 1 initialized at endpoint: https://localhost:8081/ with ConnectionMode: Direct, connection Protocol: Tcp, and consistency level: null
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Security.Claims.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'testhost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : RefreshLocationAsync() refreshing locations
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : Current WriteEndpoints = (https://127.0.0.1:8081/) ReadEndpoints = (https://127.0.0.1:8081/)
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : TimerPool Created with minSupportedTimerDelayInSeconds = 1
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : RntbdConnectionDispenser: requestTimeoutInSeconds: 10, openTimeoutInSeconds: 5, timerValueInSeconds: 1
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : Creating RNTBD TransportClient with options Rntbd.TransportClient.Options
      OpenTimeout: 00:00:05
      RequestTimeout: 00:00:10
      TimerPoolResolution: 00:00:01
      MaxChannels: 65535
      PartitionCount: 1
      MaxRequestsPerChannel: 30
      ReceiveHangDetectionTime: 00:01:05
      SendHangDetectionTime: 00:00:10
      IdleTimeout: -00:00:01
      EnableCpuMonitor: True
      UserAgent: cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.12.0|3.11.4|01|X64|Microsoft Windows 10.0.19041|.NET 5.0.7| Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos/5.0.7 Suffix:  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos/5.0.7
      CertificateHostNameOverride: 
    
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : TimerPool Created with minSupportedTimerDelayInSeconds = 1
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : CpuMonitor started
    The thread 0x44c4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : CpuMonitor started
    The thread 0x1f2c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : Opened 1 channels to server rntbd://127.0.0.1:10253/
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : Awaiting RNTBD channel initialization. Request URI: rntbd://127.0.0.1:10253/apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbServer20/partitions/a4cb4960-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : RNTBD: ConnectUnicastPortAsync connecting to rntbd://127.0.0.1:10253/ (address 127.0.0.1)
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : RNTBD connection established 127.0.0.1:51807 -> 127.0.0.1:10253
    DocDBTrace Information: 0 : RNTBD SSL handshake complete 127.0.0.1:51807 -> 127.0.0.1:10253
    The thread 0x27cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread 0x1904 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The program '[17280] testhost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

And Call Stack

```
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(char* inputPtr, int inputLength) Line 2776  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Convert.FromBase64String(string s) Line 2568  C#
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceId.FromBase64String(string s)   Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceId.Verify(string id, out byte[] buffer) Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceId.TryParse(string id, out Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceId rid)    Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PathsHelper.TryParsePathSegmentsWithDatabaseAndCollectionNames(string resourceUrl, out bool isFeed, out string resourcePath, out string resourceIdOrFullName, out bool isNameBased, out string databaseName, out string collectionName, string clientVersion, bool parseDatabaseAndCollectionNames) Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceRequest.DocumentServiceRequest(Microsoft.Azure.Documents.OperationType operationType, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceType resourceType, string path, System.IO.Stream body, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.AuthorizationTokenType authorizationTokenType, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Collections.INameValueCollection headers)  Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceRequest.Create(Microsoft.Azure.Documents.OperationType operationType, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceType resourceType, string relativePath, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.AuthorizationTokenType authorizationTokenType, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Collections.INameValueCollection headers) Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.ClientCollectionCache.ReadCollectionAsync(string collectionLink, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance) Line 61  C#
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.ClientCollectionCache.GetByNameAsync.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 52  C#
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.TaskHelper.InlineIfPossible.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 67   C#
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility<System.__Canon>.ExecuteAsync.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties>.ExecuteRetryAsync(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties>> callbackMethod, System.Func<System.Exception, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult>> callShouldRetry, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties>> inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, System.TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Action<System.Exception> preRetryCallback)  Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties>.ExecuteAsync(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties>> callbackMethod, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IRetryPolicy retryPolicy, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Action<System.Exception> preRetryCallback)   Unknown
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.TaskHelper.InlineIfPossible<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties>(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties>> function, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IRetryPolicy retryPolicy, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 80   C#
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.ClientCollectionCache.GetByNameAsync(string apiVersion, string resourceAddress, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 51  C#
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Common.CollectionCache.ResolveByNameAsync.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 253    C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties>>.InnerInvoke() Line 497  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task..cctor.AnonymousMethod__277_0(object obj) Line 2359  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread, System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Line 274  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot, System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Line 2320  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntryUnsafe(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Line 2258   C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteFromThreadPool(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Line 2243    C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() Line 641 C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Line 29   C#
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I added log output and call stack to the question.

Comment: Does the error happen after the document is saved? Maybe trying to read the data? I noticed a related issue referenced in SDK 3.18.0 as being fixed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet-standard#fixed-6 (you seem to be using 3.12). The other thing I would check is, which are the names of the collections you are working with? Any of them having any escaping characters?

Comment: I think I found, that problem is cause by the databaseName chosen (I was set to "CosmosDBdemo.cdb")    This string was tryed to Base64 decode -> Exception. No more exception when changeing databaseName. I will again verify and confirm this result. Thank you for looking at my problem!

Comment: @ruppreca please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 2):

I verified my result given in the comment above with CosmosDB (cloud) and Cosmos DB Emulator.
The problem was caused by the databaseName chosen (It was set to "CosmosDBdemo.cdb")

This string was tryed to Base64 decode in "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceId.FromBase64String(string s)" and threw the exception.
No more exception occurs when changeing databaseName.

Solution seems to be: never use a "." in a databaseName